# jQuery: How to append something after one element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

DOM

```
<div id="a">
   <div id="b"></div>
<div>

<p>Insert me after #b</p>
```

Requirement is insert p tag after '#b', and when the insert operation happened again, only replace the p tag instead of adding more.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will insert it directly after #b, within #a, but if it already exists, then it wont insert it again.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if ($('#newP').length == 0) {
    $('#b').append('<p id="newP">Insert me after #b</p>')
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function insertP(html)
{
    var a = $("#a");
    var p = a.find("p")
    if(p.length == 0)
    {
      p = $("<p></p>").appendTo(a);
    }
    p.html(html)
}
```

Comment: curious, why make a and p variables? Wouldn't my answer be less code and more efficient? i'm still learning, so i really don't know.

Comment: Since the code uses references to a across statements I prefer to use variables so that the jquery selector calls are reduced. The code could further be improving making the references to a and p global so that we can avoid the find and jquery selector for every call to insertP

Answer (score 1):

This function will remove an existing element then add a new element. If one does not exist it will simply add the element.

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
            function addAfterB(pElement) {
                    if (!$('#b ~ p')) {
                            $(pElement).insertAfter('#b');        
                    } else if ($('#b ~ p')) {
                            $('#b ~ p').remove();
                            $(pElement).insertAfter('#b')
                    }        
            }
            addAfterB('<p>New Item 1</p>');

    });
    </script>

    <div id="a">
            <div id="b"></div>
            <p>hello</p>
    <div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use $.after()...

```
<div id="a">
   <div id="b"></div>
<div>

...
<script>
   $("#b").after("<p>Insert me after #b</p>");
</script>
```